# Can the regenerate functionality of HCL OneTest Data generates the test data results in the same sequence?

Tags: schema, sequence, random-seed

When a user regenerates the data of a schema, will the regenerated test data results in the same sequence of data as it was generated earlier or will the data be shuffled?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the regenerate functionality of HCL OneTest Data, it is possible to get the same sequence of test data. In order to get the same sequence of test data while regeneration, you must enter some seed value while you generate the test data for the first time.
For more information, you can refer https://help.hcltechsw.com/onetest/hclonetestserver/10.1.2/com.hcl.test.otd.help.doc/topics/t_help_regenerate_data.html